# Error in SQL CASE in where statement during select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a query that selects 3 random items from database table but I need to apply some more logic to the query based on the value of a field in the query.

This is what I have so far hope it makes sense. Have not fully tested it yet figured I would run it through you guys first see if there is anything that jumps out.

```
SELECT ord.id, keyword, url, daily_max
  FROM orders AS ord
  LEFT JOIN product_tasks AS tsk ON tsk.id = ord.task_id
  LEFT JOIN product_groups AS grp ON grp.id = tsk.product_group
  WHERE (
    status = 'approved'  AND
    ord.total_actions_today < tsk.daily_max AND
    grp.id = 1 AND
    country_code = '$country' AND
    (   

        CASE WHEN daily_max >= 5 THEN last_displayed < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)

        CASE WHEN daily_max >10 THEN last_displayed < (NOW() - INTERAVAL 5 MINUTE)

        ELSE last_displayed < (NOW() - INTERAVAL 60 MINUTE)
    )   
  )
  GROUP BY ord.id
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 3
```

Just tested the query and as I suspected I have my syntax wrong so any help would be appreciated:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN daily_max >10 THEN last_displayed < (NOW() - INTERAVAL 5 MINUTE) ' at line 14

**Edit - Fixed**

(After several attempts + edits):

```
SELECT ord.id, keyword, url, daily_max
      FROM orders AS ord
      LEFT JOIN product_tasks AS tsk ON tsk.id = ord.task_id
      LEFT JOIN product_groups AS grp ON grp.id = tsk.product_group
      WHERE (
        status = 'approved'  AND
        ord.total_actions_today < tsk.daily_max AND
        grp.id = 1 AND
        country_code = 'us'
AND  last_displayed < 
    CASE WHEN (daily_max >= 5) THEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
         WHEN (daily_max >10) THEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
         ELSE (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
    END
    )
      GROUP BY ord.id
      ORDER BY RAND()
      LIMIT 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac4499/1

Solved DOH missing `)` in the where statement

Comment: you should specify what doesn't work or how the result is not what you want. What's the actual question here?

Comment: Just updated but this query errors out.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN daily_max >10 THEN last_displayed < (NOW() - INTERAVAL 5 MINUTE) ' at line 14

Comment: CASE syntax is `CASE WHEN condition THEN value (ELSE) condition THEN value END` and don't forget the `END`. Docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: So close now but still getting errors. I have setup a fiddle for in in the original question. Thanks for all the help so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the last_displayed out of the CASE, such that it is compared to a single value as projected out of the CASE statement:

```
WHERE...
AND  last_displayed < 
    CASE WHEN (daily_max >= 5) THEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
         WHEN (daily_max >10) THEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
         ELSE (NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
    END;
```

Also note a couple of typos - `INTERVAL` not `INTERAVAL`, and just one `CASE` is required.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beaeef/9)

Comment: I have updated the query and corrected spelling errors but it is still getting syntax error

Comment: updated and the query still errors when it is run in its entirety but the error is now at the end; statement

Comment: I updated the question with a full fiddle that is still generating error

Answer (score 1):

Your structure of your WHERE was not correct. Try the following:

```
SELECT ord.id, keyword, url, daily_max
  FROM orders AS ord
  LEFT JOIN product_tasks AS tsk ON tsk.id = ord.task_id
  LEFT JOIN product_groups AS grp ON grp.id = tsk.product_group
  WHERE (
    status = 'approved'  AND
    ord.total_actions_today < tsk.daily_max AND
    grp.id = 1 AND
    country_code = '$country' AND
    (   

        CASE WHEN daily_max >10 THEN (NOW() - INTERAVAL 5 MINUTE)
             WHEN daily_max >= 5 THEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
             ELSE (NOW() - INTERAVAL 60 MINUTE)
        END > last_displayed
    )   

  )
  GROUP BY ord.id
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 3
```